# How can I have a bullet-proof submit button with dynamic background for a search box?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, button, search-box

I was stuck, searched, tinkered, built/upgraded/tested my code and repeated this cycle tens if not over a hundred times. Now I'm stuck again and would really appreciate any kind of help.

---

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- A search button that changes graphics (1->2) smoothly when you hover
  over it and also changes when you click on it (2->3). Being a search
  button with a text box near it, it had to be in a form as a
  type="submit".
- Integrate a backup method for JQuery, so that if the user doesn't have java or something fails on his end, the .css brute rendering will take over. Is this even possible ?

---

What I've managed to do:

- Successfully created the animation of the button in the submit form using only .CSS (and a .png which contains all the animation states - image sprites)
- Successfully created the JQuery animation of the button (with smooth fade IN/OUT, but only for the mouse hovering part) - uses different individual images to alter animation;

---

**main-body-snippet:**

```
<form class="a" method="get" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" size=29 maxlength="255" style="position:relative; vertical-align:middle;">
    <input type="submit" name="button-submit" class="search_button" value="" style="border-style: none; vertical-align:middle;">
</form>
```

**.CSS used by standalone animation (without JQuery):**

```
.a input[name="button-submit"] {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url('../images/search_button.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.a input[name="button-submit"]:hover {
    background: url('../images/search_button.png') no-repeat 0px -24px;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.a input[name="button-submit"]:active {
    background: url('../images/search_button.png') no-repeat 0px -48px;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

**.CSS used by JQuery:**

```
input.search-button {
    background: transparent url(../images/search_normal.png) no-repeat left top;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 24px; 
    width: 24px; 
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 1px;
}

.search-button-wrap {
    background: transparent url(../images/search_hover.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

**And the JQuery of animating the search button:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.search-button').wrap('<div class="search-button-wrap" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"></div>');
    $('input.search-button').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ // Fade the button out when hovered
            'opacity': 0.01
        }, 300)
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ // Fade it back in on mouseout
            'opacity': 1
        }, 300)
    });
})
```

---

Where I'm stuck:

**- I am kinda stuck on making it happen in JQuery for the click part (changing animation from the hovering background to the clicked background).**

**- Also stuck at integrating the .CSS brute-animation (doesn't have fade-in-out) with the JQuery animation, as a way of real-time backup in case JQuery doesn't work on the user's client. Therefore, the pure .css animation kicks in if there is an error with the JQuery one.**

Does anyone know how to integrate a plain .css backup for the JQuery animation? Is it even at all possible? 
Even if you don't know, could you please help me out with making the .click function in JQuery work for this search button ? (on hover it transitions from normal image to hover image, and on click it must transition from hover image to clicked image)

Thanks so much guys! Any help is appreciated!